# How can I add a bulma extension to a nuxt.js project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, bulma

I want to add this package to my project https://wikiki.github.io/form/tagsinput/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://wikiki.github.io/#installation)

**Installation**

To install all extension:

```
    npm install bulma-extensions
```

To install individual extension:

```
    npm install bulma-[extensionName]
```

**Intergration**

Open your application's main `.sass` file and add the following line:

```
    @import 'bulma';
    @import '~bulma-[extensionName]';
```

And you good to go.

**Note:** You might need to add some changes in your nuxt.config.js for extra configuration.